# How to get rid of these errors?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, ssh, cocoapods

error : pod update

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `PPBlinkID` from `git@github.com:microblink/cocoapods.git`
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa':
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Firebase/Analytics (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/Core (= 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.0.0)

```
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
  Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.3.0)
```

**

> error: Pod install

**

Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `PPBlinkID` from `git@github.com:microblink/cocoapods.git`
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa':
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Firebase/Analytics (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/Core (= 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.0.0)

```
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
  Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.3.0)
```

> **error: Flutter build ios**

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Cloning into '/var/folders/4s/yrtbzwxx61nyn16hl0r0000gn/T/d20210727-82954-pqms2f'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

```
     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
     and the repository exists.
```

Error running pod install

---

> it was tried

---

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader

1- $ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
2- $ sudo gem install cocoapods-clean

3- $ pod deintegrate
4- $ pod clean
5- $ pod install

MacTrix@MacBook-Pro-de-MAC ios % **ssh-agent -s**
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/4s/yrtbzwxx6bx4bf$$$$$l0r0000gn/T//ssh-pKUpzgVDXvQz/agent.83935; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=83$$$; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 83$$$;

MacTrix@MacBook-Pro-de-MAC ios %

> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Enter passphrase for /Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /Users/mactrix/.ssh/id_rsa (""""""""@gmail.com)

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you included your podfile, version of firebase and os version in the question.